# Prevent php from executing if javascript is enabled

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I have a textarea that I want to fill using ajax if javascript is enabled in the user's browser, but use php if js is disabled. The problem is, both the ajax and the php will execute, creating a double of every input entered. I tried a noscript tag, but then nothing prints out. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Here's my html:

```
<form action="savemessage.php" method="post" id="mainChat" name="mainChat"
    onsubmit="return loadChat();">
<textarea class="historyClass" id="historyFieldjs" name="historyFieldjs" rows="40" cols="80">
<noscript>
<textarea class="historyClass" id="historyField" name="historyField" rows="40" cols="80">
<?php
echo "stuff";
?>
</textarea></noscript>
```

And javascript:

```
function loadChat()
{
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest;
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "getmessages.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            var results = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            var i;
            for(i=0; i<results.length; i++)
            {
                document.getElementById("historyFieldjs").value=
                    document.getElementById("historyFieldjs").value+result[i]+"\n";
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Have PHP fill the field, and if JavaScript is enabled, clear the field then load the data.

Comment: @RocketHazmat post answers as answers, not comments

Comment: You shouldn't waste your time making something support JavaScript disabled. JavaScript is a web standard and is enabled in all browsers by default. The only reason someone would disable it is to attempt to bridge some site security or functionality. I say to hell with them.

Comment: the reason your noscript fails is because you call document.getElementById("historyField"), which is never there to js. or wait, nvrmind, you set it twice...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to *always* have PHP fill in the field.  Then, when your page loads, if JavaScript is enabled, it can clear the field and then load the data into it.